# Pyhton Data Handling

Tags: python, dataframe

`

```
# Sorting out the data
for id, name in data:
    is_organization = False
    for pattern in organization_patterns:
        if pattern in name:
            is_organization = True
            break
        if  is_organization:
          organization_names.append((id,name))


    else:
        is_junk = False
        for keyword in junk_keywords:
            if keyword in name:
                is_junk = True
                break
        if is_junk:
            junk_data.append((id, name))

    if not is_organization and not is_junk:
        indian_names.append((id, name))


      
#output workbook
output_wb = Workbook()

# Indian names
indian_names_sheet = output_wb.create_sheet('Indian Names')

#Indian Names
indian_names_sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'ID'
indian_names_sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = 'Name'
for i, (id, name) in enumerate(indian_names):
    indian_names_sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=1).value = id
    indian_names_sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=2).value = name

# Organization Names
organization_names_sheet = output_wb.create_sheet('Organization Names')

#Organization
organization_names_sheet.cell(row=1, column=1).value = 'ID'
organization_names_sheet.cell(row=1, column=2).value = 'Name'
for i, (id, name) in enumerate(organization_names):
    organization_names_sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=1).value = id
    organization_names_sheet.cell(row=i+2, column=2).value = name
```

The above code should write data in organization names , indian names and junk data , the junk data and indian names is writing fine but its blank in organization names

It is not writing anything in organization names dont know why..

Comment: Please create a minimal example demonstrating your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What do you mean by 'it is not writing anything' in your last sentence?